# CNN Training Early Stopping

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, training-data

I am using CNN for signal classification.(two class: patient and control ). 
Using early stopping, **I want to stop training until the validation error stopped improving**. I am unable to **write the python code** to implement this.
I tried this but was unable to proceed further.

```
validation = cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict= {x:valid_x,y_:valid_y,keep_prob:1})
validation = np.append(validation,cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict= {x:valid_x,y_:valid_y,keep_prob:1}))
```

Can anyone help me with the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keras.EarlyStopping`:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)
model.fit(x, y, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

Ideally, it is good to stop training when `val_loss` increases and not when `val_acc` is stagnated. Since Kears saves a model when val_acc improves, I would recommend you leave it running and stop only when needed.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh !  I dont understand how to give input to model.fit. I have train data:train_x, train label:train_y,validation data:valid_x, and validation label:valid_y.I have implemented like below in Keras model.fit, but getting error.  I am using tensorflow in back end. Please help me.                                                                                                  
 model_info = model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data = (valid_x,valid_y), callbacks=[early_stopping])                               
 NameError: name 'model' is not defined

Comment: Given Signals are time-based, I'm no expert but I feel something like RNN with LSTM will be better, have a look here: https://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/ . Then If you still need CNN have a look at this example and see if you have done the same: https://github.com/keunwoochoi/kapre/blob/master/examples/example_codes.ipynb